# Is "found" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: tense, past-participles

> a glossary of music terms ***found*** in Shakespeare and his contemporaries.

I think this sentence is incorrect because "found" is not in the passive voice when used as the meaning of "set up" or "build".

So I suppose the sentence should be changed to:

> a glossary of music terms ***founded*** in Shakespeare and his contemporaries.

Is my opinion correct? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find this sentence somewhere? Like in a book, or on a blog? If so, you should [tell us where you found it](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). You should also give us the full sentence, and not just a fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your opinion is based on the correct rule, although it leads you *astray* a bit.  Your proposed solution

> a glossary of music terms ***founded*** in Shakespeare and his contemporaries.
>   the original.
>   makes sense grammatically.  The substituted word is *actually* in the same form, the **past participle** (sometimes called "*Participle II*"), just like

What you perhaps failed to realize is that "**found**" here **is not** the first form of the verb meaning "to build upon", "to set up", but the *Participle II* form of the verb "**find**".  In other words, the clause with which you started,

> a glossary of music terms ***found*** in Shakespeare and his contemporaries.

is *perfectly correct* and can be rewritten in *passive voice* as

> a glossary of music terms *which are<sup>1</sup>* ***found*** in Shakespeare and his contemporaries.

or in *active voice* as

> a glossary of music terms *which* *one **finds*** in Shakespeare and his contemporaries.

---

<sup>1</sup> - corrected from *which is* found -- I originally thought of "a glossary", but Demkerng T. is probably right, the fragment talks about "terms", plural.

Comment: No, I thought of "a glossary", but I'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I found something wrong in the given sentence.So I changed it from **Shakespeare and its contemporaries** to **Shakespeare and his contemporaries** in the question.

Comment: And I still could not understand the sentence well.I suppose  **Shakespeare and his contemporaries**  are some people.  How to find terms in some people? I feel it's very hard to understand in logic.Thank you.

Comment: Somebody commented on that, I thought.  "In Shakespeare..." is the shorthand version of "In **the works of** Shakespeare...".  So, if you put those missing words back you should probably see it clearer.